# Entity Framework and one to zero to zero (?) connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I got intresting situation when two kind of dependent tables sometimes must work together.

Example:

When two people from different departments to bring data, one machine, the second about the engine, do not know which engine would go to which machines and vice versa. The relationship between those tables is that the engine has optional machine and the machine has optional engine. How should look the relationships between those tables?

Model:

```
public class Machine{

    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual int MachineId { get; set; }

    public string MachineSerialNo { get; set; }

    public virtual int? MetrykiEnginedD { get; set; }
    public virtual MachineEngine MachineEngine { get; set; }
}

public class MachineEngine {

    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual int MachineEngineId { get; set; }

    public virtual string MachineEngineSN { get; set; }

    public virtual int? MachineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MachineEngine>().HasOptional(p => p.Machine) ???

modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().HasOptional(p => p.MachineEngine) ??
```

Thank you for your help.
Andrzej

Answer (score 0):

If `MetrykiEnginedD` is supposed to be a foreign key then:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>()
                    .HasOptional(p => p.MachineEngine)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.MetrykiEnginedD);
modelBuilder.Entity<MachineEngine>()
                    .HasOptional(p => p.Machine)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.MachineId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 1 'MachineEngine' can only belong to 0 or 1 'Machine',
and 1 'Machine' can only have 0 or 1 'MachineEngine' I beleive that you could configure it as follows

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().HasOptional(x => x.MachineEngine).WithOptionalDependent();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```